# Where is mongoctl after installation?

Tags: mongodb, pip, mlab

I've installed mongoctl according to Mongolab's [simple instructions](https://github.com/mongolab/mongoctl/blob/master/README.md#installation), but I can't [do anything](http://mongolab.org/#view=mongoctl) with the installed package because `which mongoctl` resolves to nothing.

The site makes it look like `pip` installs some kind of command line tool, but it seems like it just installs the python package, which would be fine if all of the documentation didn't treat `mongoctl` as a command line tool.

What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following option to your install command to ensure that "mongoctl" exe goes to /usr/local/bin

--install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"

Since mongoctl is already installed on your mac, you will probably need to add a --upgrade and a --force-reinstall

So try the following

```
sudo pip install mongoctl --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin" --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Would it be unfair to say `--install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"` should probably be documented in MogoLab's install docs?

Comment: Totally! We will be updating our docs to include that. Thanks a lot for reporting this!!

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?

'mongoctl' should be in /usr/local/bin. Check to make sure that directory is in your PATH

-will

Comment: I'm using OS X – here's the result of `ls /usr/local/bin | grep mongo` (after having run `sudo pip install mongoctl`, of course): mongo
mongod
mongodump
mongoexport
mongofiles
mongoimport
mongooplog
mongoperf
mongorestore
mongos
mongosniff
mongostat
mongotop